# Замена текстовых запросов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Например, я получаю данные через $_POST в виде:

```
$text = "(ref|https://stackoverflow.com|Текст) лучший сайт в мире";
```

Мне нужно, чтобы произошла замена на:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Текст</a> лучший сайт в мире
```

Пробовал разное, что-то типа str_replace и т.д., но не получается. Тк помимо этой строки я получаю еще текст. А заменять нужно именно эту строку + чтобы текст "лучший сайт в мире" оставался не тронутым. Есть решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = "(ref|https://stackoverflow.com|Текст) лучший сайт в мире";
$pattern = '/\((ref)\|(.*)\|(.*)\)/i';
$replacement = '<a href="$2">$3</a>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

Выведет: `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Текст</a> лучший сайт в мире`

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё решилось)

Comment: @ДмитрийФролов рад помочь ^_^

Comment: `$text = "(ref|It is not a link, dude! Yours as always, Evil Hacker with SQL Injection|Текст) лучший сайт в мире";` :)

Comment: @Other небольшое упущение =D

Comment: @Suvitruf, ну да, с этого все дыры и начинаются - не проверю-ка я размер выделенного буфера, [что может пойти не так?](https://pikabu.ru/story/da_chto_mozhet_poyti_ne_tak_5325085) :)

Answer (score 3):

Разбирать структуру с выраженным синтаксисом нужно с помощью лексера/парсера.
Особенно если это не единичный случай.

Но всё же:

```
function translate($input){
  if(preg_match("_\(ref\|((?:https?|ftp)://(?:-\.)?(?:[^\s/?\.#-]+\.?)+(?:/[^\s]*)?)\|([^\)]+)\)(.+)?_iS", $input, $matches) === false) return false;

  return "<a href='" . $matches[1] . "'>" . $matches[2] . "</a>" . $matches[3];
}

$text = "(ref|https://stackoverflow.com|Текст) - лучший сайт в мире";
var_dump(translate($text)); // string(86) "<a href='https://stackoverflow.com'>Текст</a> - лучший сайт в мире"
```

[Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FuzzyUnpleasantMosasaur)

Comment: Благодарю, очень интересное решение)